# How to delete aws cognito userpool with deletion protection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

can not delete aws cognito userpool with deletion protection.
I have deleted iam role for cognito userpool so I can not confirm external Id.

Comment: What do you mean you can't delete it? What is the error? If you login with root user to AWS console, you can delete it

Comment: Error message  is "InvalidSmsRoleTrustRelationshipException". I could not delete with root user.